# tf-nightly-gpu, keras, and Sequential()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've recently updated my GPU and moved to tf-nightly-gpu. Unfortunately, my changes have broken my code. I've been reading about the changes and I've stripped my code back to the few lines below in an effort to focus in on the issue.  I'm not sure if it an issue with imports or syntax (I'm still a rookie here).

I've pulled the exact section of the guide and worry that the answer is right in front of me and I'm missing it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?version=nightly

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the keras model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

And this is what I'm getting for an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grimace/PycharmProjects/Evo/HouseTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'
```

I've tried moving things around and the result is a new error each time, but at this point I think I'm only making it worse. Also, I need to be on nightly because for hardware support.

Comment: Can you import tensorflow in a python shell and then report the output of print(tensorflow) and print(tensorflow.__version__) ?

Comment: Here is the output:  <module 'tensorflow' (namespace)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grimace/PycharmProjects/Evo/HouseTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(tf.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: Seems that somehow your whole tensorflow installation is empty, unfortunately no idea what produces that and how to fix it, just try to reinstall tensorflow?

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled and now the output is: <module 'tensorflow' from 'C:\\Users\\Grimace\\PycharmProjects\\Evo\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\__init__.py'>
2.5.0-dev20201207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info Dr. Snoopie gave me in the comments I was able to used `print(__path__)` to see where it was looking and I removed everything TF related and reinstalled. This resolved the issue.

Not sure if there would have been a cleaner way to do it, but it worked.